# How can I return the entry with the highest value?

Tags: templating

Each entry in `posts` has a field called `value`.  `Value` is a number.

**For a `category`, how can I return the entry with the highest value?**

This is not for Craft Commerce.  Value represents a budget figure.

Alternatively...

How can I return the top 3 entries (based on value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a combination of the `orderBy` and `relatedTo` [entry query params](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/element-query-params/entry-query-params.html).

This may put you on the right track?

```
{% set topThree = craft.entries({
  section: 'posts',
  relatedTo: { targetElement: myCategory },
  orderBy: 'myBudgetValueField desc',
  limit: 3
}).all %}
```

Alternatively, for just the entry with the highest value:

```
{% set topFigure = craft.entries({
  section: 'posts',
  relatedTo: { targetElement: myCategory },
  orderBy: 'myBudgetValueField desc'
}).one %}
```

Of course, this depends on `myBudgetValueField` being a number or some other easily-sortable value. If you need to format the value, I'd recommend storing it in the unit for comparison, and then visually treating it when you output it (i.e. store `300000`, even if you eventually need to output `$300,000`).